# Force showing icon and title in BottomNavigationView support android

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

After adding 4 items in my menu.xml file for the BottomNavigationView it shows only selected item title and hides all other titles.
Can I force showing the title and the icon. 
here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_24dp"
    android:title="@string/text_home"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_category"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_grid_24dp"
    android:title="@string/text_category"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_me"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_me_24dp"
    android:title="@string/text_me"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_setting"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_cog_24dp"
    android:title="@string/text_setting"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

---

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:translationZ="6dp"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this code,

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.segunfamisa.sample.bottomnav.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f1f1f1">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_menu.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.segunfamisa.sample.bottomnav.MenuFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Make this file inside **menu** folder,

**bottom_nav_items.xml** :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
        android:title="One"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_category"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:title="Two"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_me"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:title="Three"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_setting"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_popup_reminder"
        android:title="Four"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String SELECTED_ITEM = "arg_selected_item";

    private BottomNavigationView mBottomNav;
    private int mSelectedItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        disableShiftMode(mBottomNav);
        mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                selectFragment(item);
                return true;
            }
        });

        MenuItem selectedItem;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSelectedItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM, 0);
            selectedItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().findItem(mSelectedItem);
        } else {
            selectedItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);
        }
        selectFragment(selectedItem);
    }

    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            //Timber.e(e, "Unable to get shift mode field");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            //Timber.e(e, "Unable to change value of shift mode");
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM, mSelectedItem);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        MenuItem homeItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);
        if (mSelectedItem != homeItem.getItemId()) {
            // select home item
            selectFragment(homeItem);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private void selectFragment(MenuItem item) {
        Fragment frag = null;
        // init corresponding fragment
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_home:
                frag = MenuFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.text_home),
                        getColorFromRes(R.color.color_home));
                break;
            case R.id.action_category:
                frag = MenuFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.text_notifications),
                        getColorFromRes(R.color.color_notifications));
                break;
            case R.id.action_me:
                frag = MenuFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.text_search),
                        getColorFromRes(R.color.color_search));
                break;
            case R.id.action_setting:
                frag = MenuFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.text_home),
                        getColorFromRes(R.color.color_home));
                break;
        }

        // update selected item
        mSelectedItem = item.getItemId();

        // uncheck the other items.
        for (int i = 0; i < mBottomNav.getMenu().size(); i++) {
            MenuItem menuItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(i);
            menuItem.setChecked(menuItem.getItemId() == item.getItemId());
        }

        updateToolbarText(item.getTitle());

        if (frag != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.container, frag, frag.getTag());
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    private void updateToolbarText(CharSequence text) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle(text);
        }
    }

    private int getColorFromRes(@ColorRes int resId) {
        return ContextCompat.getColor(this, resId);
    }
```

**MenuFragment.java :**

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_TEXT = "arg_text";
    private static final String ARG_COLOR = "arg_color";

    private String mText;
    private int mColor;

    private View mContent;
    private TextView mTextView;

    public static Fragment newInstance(String text, int color) {
        Fragment frag = new MenuFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TEXT, text);
        args.putInt(ARG_COLOR, color);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // retrieve text and color from bundle or savedInstanceState
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            mText = args.getString(ARG_TEXT);
            mColor = args.getInt(ARG_COLOR);
        } else {
            mText = savedInstanceState.getString(ARG_TEXT);
            mColor = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_COLOR);
        }

        // initialize views
        mContent = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_content);
        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);

        // set text and background color
        mTextView.setText(mText);
        mContent.setBackgroundColor(mColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString(ARG_TEXT, mText);
        outState.putInt(ARG_COLOR, mColor);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

whatever you need to do is just **disable BottomNavigationView Shift mode**,
using this method in you code.

```
public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            //Timber.e(e, "Unable to get shift mode field");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            //Timber.e(e, "Unable to change value of shift mode");
        }
    }
```

call this method like this,

```
mBottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        disableShiftMode(mBottomNav);
```

It will work.I am attaching screenshot here,

[image]

Comment: This solution won't work on Android 9 (P), Instead try solution provided by 
@QtJambiii

Comment: This is not the best answer.. the best answer is provided by @qinmiao here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52639855/1053190

Answer (score 23):

It's just simply like this:

**Kotlin**

```
bottomNavigationView.labelVisibilityMode=LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED
```

**Java**

```
bottomNavigationView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED)
```

Comment: Great one liner solution without losing the shifting effect.

Comment: Can't find setLabelVisibilityMode method in BottomNavigationView ?

Comment: try with support library 28.0.0-alpha1

Comment: yeah, still cannot use in API 27 or later

Comment: cannot use in API 26

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks.  It can also be specified in the xml:
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"

Comment: `LabelVisibilityMode` is now deprecated. You should use `NavigationBarView.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED`

Answer (score 9):

after support library 28.0.0, support LabelVisibilityMode.

xml config: app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
          android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"
          android:background="?bottom_tint_color"
          app:elevation="@dimen/padding_4"
          app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
          app:itemIconTint="?drawer_tint_color"
          app:itemTextColor="?drawer_tint_color"
          app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_lite"/>
```

or

you can call :

```
BottomNavigationView.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
```

Answer (score 7):

Above one i find a bit longer solution for this problem. I had a simpler solution for it.

Add this class in your app:

```
class BottomNavigationViewHelper {

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
public static void removeShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    try {
        Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
            item.setShiftingMode(false);
            // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
            item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
        }

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR NO SUCH FIELD", "Unable to get shift mode field");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR ILLEGAL ALG", "Unable to change value of shift mode");
    }
}
```

}

and then add this in your activity where bottomnavigationview is available

```
BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);//disable BottomNavigationView shift mode
```

This will disable shifting mode of navigationview and text and icon will be shown always.

Answer (score 3):

Starting on support library 28-alpha, we can use `app:labelVisibilityMode` attribute on BottomNavigation component. The value we can use, there are `labeled`, `unlabeled`, `selected`, and `auto`.

- `labeled` will keep all labels visible.
- `unlabeled` will show only icons.
- `selected` will only show the label for the selected item and shift
  items.
- `auto` will choose labeled or selected based on the number of items we
  have labeled for 1–3 items and selected for 3+ items.

---

This is some example of using it :

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/mainBottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:elevation="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 navigation = (BottomNavigationView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);


     try{disableShiftMode(navigation);}catch(Exception ew){}
```

Make this method in your Activity or Fragment where you want to call:

```
 @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    try {
        Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
            item.setShiftingMode(false);

            item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {

    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

    }
}
```